# User-specific discounted products via Shopify API?

Tags: shopify

Is there any way to create discounted products that only appear at specific times and places (through the Shopify API)?  I've just been creating variants with lower prices, but this is a bit troublesome since I need to modify all product-rendering Liquid files so that discount price doesn't show up anywhere.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In a word:  no.  They've been planning it for years, but as of now there is still no way to create individual discounts via the API.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if I exactly understood but let me try... You can change the product prices using the API for sure. Also, you can create a collection and use the API to insert this product in this collection. Finally, using liquid you show this collection. Some dynamic you may add with jquery or script. Also, you can use the user system to define which user can or not view it. This is only a suggestion.

Comment: How can I choose which users to exclude or include through the API?  I want to exclude all users from a collection such that no one knows the collection exists.  Is this possible?

Comment: This is a reference for customer in the API: http://docs.shopify.com/api/customer. To create different users segment you could apply tags, for example. Now talking about liquid, you can use variable customer (http://wiki.shopify.com/Customer_variable) to control when it shows the collection or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by using customer tags. Since you can control what gets displayed when checking the customer tags, you can pull in products priced just for them.

Comment: My problem isn't so much "choosing when to display the products" as it is "hiding the products everywhere else on the shop."  I can create the discounted variants (or products if this is easier), but I don't want them to be displayed anywhere on the site.  And I want to do this without modifying a lot of Liquid files or using a JavaScript hack.